# Is there a Collection that hold implementations to an abstract generic class with multiple types

Tags: c#, generics, collections, abstract-class

I have this abstract class, and implementations, which has an Input type and Output type:

```
public abstract class Action<TInput, TOutput> 
{
    public Action() {}

    public virtual TOutput Execute(TInput input)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}

public class Foo<int, string> : Action<int, string>
{
    public override string Execute(int i)
    {
        ...
    }
}

public class Bar<string, int> : Action<string, int>
{
    public override int Execute(string s)
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

How can I hold these imp. in a Collection and loop through them?

like:

```
actions.Add(new Foo());
actions.Add(new Bar());

object obj;

foreach(var item in actions)
    obj = item.Execute(obj);
```

Comment: You can have a collection of common base class, in this case `System.Object`, or of an interface that both implement.  For example, you could make `Action<TInput, TOutput>` implement an interface `IAction` with a method `object Execute(object o)`; then have a collection of `IAction`.

Comment: You should make `Execute` an `abstract` method. That way when someone inherits from the class they know they have to override it. If they don't they get a compile error. A `virtual` method that throws `NotImplementedException` allows you to create an inherited class that compiles, but then fails at runtime.

Comment: @Joe This won't work, unless you change the signatures of the existing Execute methods (or add an overload)

Comment: @Adrian, implement ... `object Execute(object o)` implies adding an overload or explicit interface implementation, I agree.  The implementation depends on what the OP wants to achieve, but his sample code shows a call using an `object` argument.  Possibly he could implement it by casting the `object` parameter to `TInput` and calling `Action<TInput, TOutput>.Execute(TInput input)`.  Perhaps with type checking and an `ArgumentException` if the input `object` value is not the right type.

Comment: Why would you want to put these in the same list? You can’t use them the same way.

Comment: I love this question and questions like it. Really. But it's worth noting that the *literal* question is answered *in* the question. You're able to define a collection and put your things in it, so the answer is, "yes, there is a collection" - `List<T>`. As you've already seen, it can hold multiple types - `T` or anything that inherits from it. So the question isn't really whether there is a collection type, but how to interact with the items in the collection.

Comment: @ScottHannen correction: it can hold multiple objects of type T (that's it) it can't hold objects of type derived from T. The type parameter T is not covariant.

Comment: @SamuelVidal - you can't cast the list as a list of a derived type. But if is of that type, you can put it in the list. If you create a list of object you can put anything in it.

Comment: Ah yes that's it you are right, I stand corrected. Thanks for reminding me.

Answer (score 0):

You can't quite do what you're trying to do.

```
actions.Add(new Foo()); // expects and returns string
actions.Add(new Bar()); // expects and returns int

object obj;

foreach(var item in actions)
    obj = item.Execute(obj);
```

If `Foo` expects `string` and `Bar` expects `int` (and technically any implementation could expect any other type) then what value can you pass to each item in the collection that will work with all of them? Also, what would you do with the return values, since each of them could be of a different type?

You can solve the problem of getting it *compile* by declaring the inputs and outputs as `object`, although that would defeat the purpose of making it generic. You would just replace your base class with this...

```
public abstract class Action 
{
    public abstract object Execute(object input);
}
```

...but that wouldn't be a very useful class.

But the real problem is that methods that receive and return `object` aren't *usually* very useful either. The type system allows us to know the types of arguments, return values, variables, etc. That's part of what indicates the intent of our code. For example, we write a method like this:

```
bool IsAnagram(string input)
```

because we want to know *if* (`bool`) an *input* (`string`) is an anagram. Knowing that it does that is our reason for calling it. If we don't want to know if a `string` is an anagram, we don't call this method because we don't need it.

But what if we have a method like this:

```
object GetResult(object input)
```

It has no reason to exist. Why would we call it? If we have a value of some type and we want to do something with it and get some result, we would write a method that does that.

Similarly, if we get back `object` from the method, what do we do with it? We don't know what it is. It's a bit like going to the store to buy something, except we have nothing in mind that we want to buy, and they hand us a package and we don't know what's inside. We couldn't have any plans for what we intended to do when we got it, since we didn't know what we would get. So we just wouldn't do it.

It only makes sense to use `object` in specific scenarios where we don't care what the type is. Those scenarios are less common because in order for our application to do anything it almost always needs to be doing something with specified types - creating them, getting them from somewhere, passing them to other methods, and getting more expected types in return.

---

If you just want a collection of *things to do*, and they all take different arguments and return different types, then you have to declare the collection according to its least common denominator, which is just [`Action`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.action) with no arguments and no return values.

You could do this:

```
var actions = new List<Action>();

actions.Add(() =>
{
    var foo = new Foo();
    foo.Execute(5);
});

actions.Add(() =>
{
    var bar = new Bar();
    bar.Execute("Hello!");
});

foreach (var action in actions)
{
    action.Invoke();
}
```

...and there may be cases where a collection of `Action` is useful. But in most cases there's no reason to take a bunch of unrelated actions that do different things and put them in a collection with each other.

Answer (score 0):

You can't. At least not with `Execute` remaining type safe.
What you can do is create another base class or an interface that declares an `Execute` method that receives and returns an `object`:

```cs
public interface IAction {
    object Execute(object input);
}

public abstract class Action<TInput, TOutput> : IAction {
    public object Execute(object input) {
        return Execute((TInput) input);
    }

    public virtual TOutput Execute(TInput input)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

This will then work (it will compile):

```cs
List<IAction> actions = new List<IAction>();
actions.Add(new Foo());
actions.Add(new Bar());

object obj;

foreach(var item in actions)
    obj = item.Execute(obj);
```

However! Keep in mind that this will compile but produce a runtime error:

```cs
IAction action = new Foo(); // Expects an integer
action.Execute("I'm not an integer");
```

The string will be cast to object and then to int, which won't work.